# Java - Obtaining individual substrings for an entered string

Tags: java, substring

I'm trying to use utilize a space `" "` to separate words within a String that a user inputs. Regardless of the entered string, the space will separate each word. In addition to this, I cannot use `split()` since this is the most common solution I have found thus far online. Only utilizing `substring()` is allowed.

In my failed attempts, I have only been capable of obtaining the first inputted word (ex. "Random"), but cannot separate the second and third words (ex. "Access Memory"). I'm not going to publish my failed attempts, but I am asking for the code that might help me just to IDENTIFY each word, not print each individual word please?

For example: `x = foo.substring(1, firstWord);`

P.S. I know this is used to create acronyms, I can do that part, just need to identify each substring.

```
public class ThreeLetterAcronym {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (firstWord < wordsInput.length()) {
            if (wordsInput.charAt(firstWord) == ' ') {
                first = wordsInput.substring(0,firstWord);
                second = wordsInput.substring(firstWord + 1, wordsInput.length());
                // I know that this is the spot where the last two words are
                // displayed in the output, this is the closest I have been to
                // displaying anything relevant.
                firstWord = wordsInput.length();
            }

            ++firstWord;
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Original phrase was: " 
            + initialInput + "\nThree letter acronym is: " + first + second);
    }
}
```

Comment: >In addition to this, I cannot use .split since this is the most common solution I have found thus far online
 and what's the problem with it? Is it a homework?

Comment: yes, it is. We can only identify each word with a .substring :)

Comment: You can use String.indexOf, right? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String)

Comment: use second argument to .substring method to search for spaces other that the first

Comment: @user3304613 Exactly, that's the point.

Comment: are you allowed to use regular expressions?

Comment: can you please explain what you mean by "regular expressions?"

Comment: Please accept the best answer by clicking on the `(tick symbol)`. It will help people with similar issues to select their answer with ease next time. `Upvoting` and `accepting` an answer motivates people to answer more.

Answer (score 2):

```
   String tmp = wordsInput.trim();

   int spaceIndex = tmp.indexOf(" ");
   first = tmp.substring(0,spaceIndex);
   tmp = tmp.substring(spaceIndex+1);
   tmp = tmp.trim();

   spaceIndex = tmp.indexOf(" ");
   second = tmp.substring(0, spaceIndex);
   tmp = tmp.trim();

   third = tmp.substring(spaceIndex+1);
```

You can use a loop to improve the code. I hope that will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use indexof(" ") that would be a tidy way to go through the string until indexOf returns -1 and substring on the result of that.  This would be a good candidate for a recursive function.

```
findStrings(String input, ArrayList<String> stringList){
    if(input.indexOf(" ") < 0)
        return;
    stringList.add(input.subString(0,input.indexOf(" "))
    input = input.subString(input.indexOf(" "));
    return findString(input, stringList);

}
```

Something like that.  Modulo off by one and stuff like that on the string indices, but I'll let you figure that out.

Comment: Wait, no... sorry. I can't use an array. @Dylan

Comment: using the code provided, like how I identified the first word up to the first space with "first," is there a way to identify the other two entered words using the space without using .split or an array?

Answer (score 1):

here is the straight forward answer for your question, though recursive one provided by Dylan is more effective, following will help you understand what is happening

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "hi hello how are you";
    List<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = 0;
    boolean done = false;
    index = str.indexOf(" ");
    while(!done){
        String newStr = null;
        if(index == -1){
            newStr = str;
        }else{
            newStr = str.substring(0,index);
        }
        wordList.add(newStr);
        if(index == -1){
            str = "";
        }else{
            str = str.substring(index).trim();
        }
        if(!(str.length() > 0)){
            done = true;
        }else{
            index = str.indexOf(" ");
        }
    }
    for(String string : wordList){
        System.out.println(string);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the Scanner class, you can set it up so it uses a specified delimiter. Take a look at Oricals website http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html
This website should show you all the scanner methods you can use as well as implementing and setting up this class